# JSFiddle doesn't work even if I copy code from another working fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I visited this link to get some help in learning how to play around with Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZtqL/1/

I attempted it on my project. Didn't work. Hmm.
So I made a new JS Fiddle and copied to code over. Still didn't work.. Why?
Here's my fiddle which doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/mt6bwry9/

The code is an exact copy.

Here's the code used:

```js
var text="This text will be written one by one.";
var delay=200;
var elem = $("#myText");
//text- string
//elem - jQuery element where text is to be attached
//delay - the delay in each text
var addTextByDelay = function(text,elem,delay){
    if(!elem){
        elem = $("body");
    }
    if(!delay){
        delay = 300;
    }
    if(text.length >0){
        //append first character 
        elem.append(text[0]);
        setTimeout(
            function(){
                //Slice text by 1 character and call function again                
                addTextByDelay(text.slice(1),elem,delay);            
             },delay                 
            );
    }
}

addTextByDelay(text,elem,delay);
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="myText"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You didn't include jQuery in the fiddle. big clues in browser console and in your own page probably using this before elements exist

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Click "JavaScript options" on the top-right corner of the JS window, and configure your fiddle properly.

Comment: Probably related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: add jquery library on console it gives error please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said you're new to JavaScript, here is a little more detailed answer.

If your JavaScript isn't behaving the way you expect it to, definitely check your browser console. You can do that in Chrome by going to View>>Developer>>JavaScript Console or simply pressing Command+Alt+J. In other browsers you will find similar developer tools.

In the case of your JS Fiddle, when you open the console you see an error that says `$ is not defined`. `$` is shorthand for jQuery. The JavaScript code that you've copied from the other Fiddle uses jQuery to do DOM Manipulation and your Fiddle hasn't loaded jQuery. So click on the gear icon in your JS section and under Frameworks select jQuery (I recommend 2.2.1) and try running your code again.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even know there was a console. But now I do. Thank you! Adding jQuery solved it.